# How to make a box-whisker plot with Mean, SEM, and Std in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I've tried to make a box-whisker plot using matplotlib and seaborn, but still haven't found the right way to make the one I am looking for. The last time I tried using seaborn boxplot, but turns out it's the usual boxplot with median, quartile, max, min, and outliers. The plot that I made can be seen [`here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FSss.png).

Here is the code for my example.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Method':['RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','RD','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Spectral','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch','Mini Batch'],
'Dataset':['B2F','B2F','B2F','B2F','B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B2F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F', 'B5F'], 
'ARI':[0.25, 0.09, 0.03, 0.63, 0.46, 0.29, 0.56, 0.41, 0.28, 0.4, 0.22, 0.07, 0.99, 0.78, 0.43, 0.46, 0.33, 0.24, 0.34, 0.25, 0.06, 0.78, 0.61, 0.23, 0.81, 0.75, 0.37, 0.35, 0.33, 0.02, 0.73, 0.56, 0.28, 0.81, 0.76, 0.47, 0.32, 0.32, 0.01, 0.75, 0.54, 0.27, 0.81, 0.76, 0.43, 0.25, 0.29, 0.95, 0.84, 0.91, 0.92, 0.74, 0.75, 0.8, 0.25, 0.26, 0.99, 0.79, 0.87, 0.54, 0.74, 0.77, 0.66, 0.25, 0.25, 0.99, 0.79, 0.79, 0.95, 0.78, 0.81, 0.8, 0.27, 0.22, 0.11, 0.8, 0.67, 0.36, 0.81, 0.71, 0.48, 0.26, 0.22, 0.1, 0.8, 0.65, 0.34, 0.81, 0.74, 0.49, 0.27, 0.22, 0.1, 0.79, 0.67, 0.36, 0.81, 0.74, 0.5, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.81, 0.8, 0.79, 0.81, 0.81, 0.75, 0.26, 0.26, 0.27, 0.82, 0.81, 0.77, 0.81, 0.81, 0.78, 0.25, 0.27, 0.26, 0.81, 0.79, 0.75, 0.81, 0.81, 0.77]})

sns.boxplot(x="Method", y="ARI", hue="Dataset", data=df, width=0.5)
plt.show()
```

What I have been trying to make is box-whisker plot with Mean, SEM, and Std similar to [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYpdj.png) taken from:
Ganse, B., Behrens, P. and Benthien, J.P., 2008. Two-stage hip revision arthroplasty: the role of the excision arthroplasty. European Journal of Orthopaedic Surgery & Traumatology, 18(3), pp.223-228.

Is it also possible to still be able to get the maximum and/or minimum value as well as the sample size shown in each plot? This is optional, but it will be great if anyone can give me the idea.

Update: I've tried using barchart with errorbar (Std) and adding maximum values using dot plot, and adding number of sample label, shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU2uU.png). Do you think it is ok to use this kind of visualization instead?

Thank you for anyone who have seen this question and many more thanks for those who are trying to help. I'm looking forward for an insight.

Comment: Maybe [Box plot with min, max, average and standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328774/box-plot-with-min-max-average-and-standard-deviation) is helpful for your situation? Anyway, probably you'll need to create your custom plot in custom way. I.e. drawing boxes, lines for mean and error bars in separate steps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion @JohanC, I guess it will do. But I don't think errorbar can handle unequal sample size? In the end, I've tried using barchart with errorbar and adding maximum values using dot plot, and adding number of sample label. Do you think it is ok to use this kind of visualization?

Comment: How about you create new columns of std and mean value then use seaborn?

Comment: Your DataFrame has a typo error, correct it

Comment: Could you explain more specifically about the application of seaborn that you meant? And which part of error that you are talking about? Thank you so much for the response @pyaj

Comment: You forgot to add the semi column between method and list