# Boxplot with python and known min, max, average values

Tags: python, boxplot

If I have the following data, how can I create a box plot for each metric for each gender?
Can it be done if I only know the min, max and avg values?

| gender | metric | vmin | max | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | Height | 160.0 | 170.0 | 165.0 |
| Male | Weight | 70.0 | 80.0 | 75.0 |
| Female | Height | 150.0 | 160.0 | 155.0 |
| Female | Weight | 50.0 | 60.0 | 55.0 |

```
data = [['Male', 'Height', 160.0, 170.0, 165.0],
        ['Male', 'Weight', 70.0, 80.0, 75.0],
        ['Female', 'Height', 150.0, 160.0, 155.0],
        ['Female', 'Weight', 50.0, 60.0, 55.0],
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["gender", "metric", "min", "max", "avg"])
```

From what I've tried, it seems the actual values are required rather than already known min/max/avg.

As mentioned by Talha, I'd need the values that derived the min Max and average to create such a plot, hence not accepting the suggested answer, it uses such values.

I can create such a plot by drawing some vertical lines between min and Max, then scatter plot on the lines for the average values.

The plot will be just like a min-Max-avg plot that can be created in Excel (a quick web search shows what they look like)

Comment: A boxplot depicts quantiles. You can't derive these from what you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Box plot with min, max, average and standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328774/box-plot-with-min-max-average-and-standard-deviation)

Comment: You also need standard deviation (or variance)